# UIWebView sizeThatFits incorrect in Landscape mode, multiple paragpraphs

Tags: objective-c

I Have a UIView in a UINavigationController view stack. Inside the UIView I have a UIWebView, which gets populated with HTML formatted text (originally download from an xml file and stored in coredata).

I want the UIWebView to expand vertically to fit the content so I call this code:

```
int screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width - 40;
CGRect frame = descText.frame;
frame.size.height = 1;
frame.size.width = screenWidth;
descText.frame = frame;
CGSize fittingSize = [descText CGSizeZero];
frame.size = fittingSize;
```

This works fine when the View is loaded in Portrait mode but when loaded in landscape. it expands too far, nearly double. The reason for this is that sizeThatFits returns a height that is far too big:

```
2011-05-05 14:16:20.268 DesignFedApp[2792:207]  CURRENT SIZE: {293, 592} FITTING SIZE: {293, 592}
2011-05-05 14:16:26.282 DesignFedApp[2792:207] new orientation = 4
2011-05-05 14:16:26.283 DesignFedApp[2792:207] new orientation = 4    
2011-05-05 14:16:26.283 DesignFedApp[2792:207] ROOT!! willRoatetToInterfaceOrientation!!!!!!!!!!!
2011-05-05 14:16:27.452 DesignFedApp[2792:207] CELL CLICKED: 1
2011-05-05 14:16:27.452 DesignFedApp[2792:207] LocNavController locSelected
2011-05-05 14:16:27.453 DesignFedApp[2792:207] Loc: The Hood
2011-05-05 14:16:27.459 DesignFedApp[2792:207] should rotate to LANDSCAPE
2011-05-05 14:16:27.481 DesignFedApp[2792:207] POSITION ELEMENTS view.width {{0, 0}, {480, 268}}
2011-05-05 14:16:27.483 DesignFedApp[2792:207]  CURRENT SIZE: {440, 761} FITTING SIZE: {440, 761}
```

The really weird thing is that this does not happen when the HTML being loaded only consists of 1 p tag!!!! Multiple

tags and we have the issue described above. But only in Landscape.

So to re-cap. UIWebView sizeThatFits return incorrect height, but only in landscape mode and only when html has more than one p tag.

If anyone can shed any light on this it could save me weeks of time, I've been reading though so many forums and all the Apple docs but haven't found anything that can help me with this specific case.

Thanks in advance, Ian.

**EDIT:** OK I've noticed that the problem only occurs if the loaded HTML String has more than 1 tag set in it:

```
NSString *html=@"<p>This is a parapgrah this will work fine......</p>";
NSString *html2=@"<p>This is a paragraph with other <i>tags</i>, this wont work properly</p>";
```

Whole Method. Called from webViewDidFinishLoad:webView

```
-(void)positionElements:(BOOL)inLandScape{
NSLog(@"position elements");
//stretch frame to fit content
int screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width - 40;
CGRect frame = descText.frame;
frame.size.height = 1;
frame.size.width = screenWidth;
descText.frame = frame;
CGSize fittingSize = [descText sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
NSLog(@"fittingSize: %@",NSStringFromCGSize(fittingSize));
frame.size = fittingSize;
descText.frame = frame;
//position buttons underneath
CGRect mapBtnFrame = showOnMapBtn.frame;
mapBtnFrame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + frame.size.height + 20;
showOnMapBtn.frame = mapBtnFrame;
CGRect locBtnFrame = locationInfoBtn.frame;
locBtnFrame.origin.y = mapBtnFrame.origin.y + mapBtnFrame.size.height + 20;
locationInfoBtn.frame = locBtnFrame;

CGRect scrollFrame = self.view.frame;
scrollFrame.size.height -= 49;
container.frame = scrollFrame;

CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
for (UIView *containerSubView in container.subviews)
    contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, containerSubView.frame);
container.contentSize = contentRect.size;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain further? Which is incorrect, the UIWebView's frame's height or the height of the scrollable area?

Comment: The UIWebView frame height is wrong after calling sizeThatFits. Surely if the width is bigger than when I called it in protrait mode, then the height that fits will be smaller, not larger. But again, this only happens if the text has more than one p tag

Comment: Are you saying you don't want the `UIWebView` to scroll at all? You're saying that if you rotate to landscape mode and the `UIWebView` gets wider as a result, you also want it to get shorter so that it is only tall enough to display the HTML content?

Comment: Showing your whole code would be helpful. You don't call `sizeThatFits` anywhere in the excerpt you posted above.

Comment: @Byan Irace Thats exacty what I want to happen. The weird thing I've noticed is that it works, even in landscape mode, but only if the HTML string being loaded does not have multiple paragraph tags, or line break tags inside a paragraph. Its got to be something to do with the format of the html string. Have you ever heard of any problems like this? Cheers.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm currently experience the current same thing, where the UIWebView is displayed incorrectly when there is more than one p-tag in the HTML string. I really hope you found a solution to this problems.

Comment: @dhrm: have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `UINavigationController` and you want your `UIWebView` to take up the whole content area, you shouldn't need to manually set the frame at all. You should just be able to call `[view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];` on both the `UIView` and the `UIWebView` subview.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick replay. Unfortunately I dont want the UIWebview to fill the whole UIView because I want some other stuff like image scroller and buttons above and below it. I'm only using UIWebview so the text that I load can be formatted using HTML (the easiest way to format it I guess).

Comment: The weird thing is that it all works fine, if the HTML only has one p tag. really weird. any ideas on that?

Comment: @IanEllis: any updates? Have you found the solution ?